# {cases} does not work while amsmath package is used

Tags: amsmath, cases

I tried the following:

```
$P_{ijt}^{bool}$: \begin{cases} 1 & \mbox{if } P_{ijt} > 0 \\ 0 & \mbox{else} \end{cases}
```

`\usepackage{amsmath}` is in the beginning of the file.

This should work according to numerous websites, but I get the following error:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.216 $P_
        {ijt}^{bool}$: \begin{cases} 1 & \mbox{if } P_{ijt} > 0 \\ 0 & \mbox{...
```

Can someone tell me what I am missing?
Or how I can define this variable with a large accolade in a different way?

Comment: `\begin{cases}…\end{cases}` should be inside math mode (for instance `\[ … \]`). By the way, as always, if you post a minimal *compilable* example so we can reproduce your problem (from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`) it's much more likely that you get a correct answer.

Answer (score 7):

the `cases` environment must be inside math mode.

the correct way to code this expression is

```
$P_{ijt}^{bool}:
 \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } P_{ijt} > 0 \\
               0 & \text{...} ...
 \end{cases}
$
```

(note that i used `\text` rather than `\mbox` so that if a text string appears in a
subscript or superscript, the correct size will be used.)

Answer (score 3):

When we read the error message shown in your question then we can say that the mentioned error have nothing to do with `\begin{cases}...\end{cases}`. The source line is broken in the place of the problem, i.e. in the `_` character used after P. This "index creating command" can be used only in math mode.

We can see, that the `$` is preceded to the P letter, but from the error message follows that this first `$` at the mentioned line is not first `$` in the paragraph (which we cannot see, because you didn't show whole text). Very probably, there are odd number of `$` before the mentioned line.

Of course, if you correct the number of dollars before the mentioned line then you have to move the second `$` after `{bool}` to the end of `{cases}` because `{cases}` work in math mode only.

I recommend to use some text editor which is able to colorize the math mode inside paragraph. Then you need not count the number of dollars in each paragraph.